# Check room availability for a hotel booking system

Tags: php, datetime

Basically, I'm trying to make a hotel booking room system using PHP and MySQL, I did my research and found a lot of explanations about making a new booking over an existing one, the problem I have now is when I have multiple bookings (2 or more) and I create a new one, here is an exemple of what's happening :

- Booking N.01 : 2021-10-25 to 2021-10-27 => (Available) / Works !
- Booking New : 2021-10-26 to 2021-10-30 => (Not available) / Works !

Then :

- Booking N.01 : 2021-10-25 to 2021-10-27 => (Available) / Works !
- Booking N.02 : 2021-10-28 to 2021-10-30 => (Available) / Works !
- Booking New : 2021-10-25 to 2021-10-27 => (Available) / Not working ! It's not supposed to be available because of the range of Booking N.01 but since the range of Booking N.02 is fine with it, it still says available...

  ```
           "SELECT * From T_Chambres
           LEFT JOIN T_Reservation ON T_Reservation.RefChambre = T_Chambres.NoChambre 
           WHERE (
               T_Chambres.TypeChambre='$LeChoix'
               AND T_Reservation.RefChambre IS NULL
           )
           OR (
               T_Chambres.TypeChambre='$LeChoix' 
               AND (T_Reservation.DateDebutRes >= ? OR  ? >= T_Reservation.DateFinRes)
           ) LIMIT 1");
           $stmt->bind_param("ss", $DateFin, $DateDebut);
           $stmt->execute();
  ```

Comment: Please note that if ONE (or more) of the following 3 conditions is true, then the time slot (start date=T1 , end date=T2) is overlapping with an existing slot and should be marked as "unavailable" : (1) T1 >= start date of any slot and T1 <= end date of the slot , (2) T2 >= start date of any slot and T2 <= end ate of the slot, (3) T1 >= start date of any slot and T2 <=end date of the slot.

Comment: Why isn't `'$LeChoix'` parameterized?

Comment: What does this question have to do with mysqli?

Comment: '$LeChoix' represents the choice of the room, I don't need it to be call in the part of code that I need help with, that's why I didn't show the PHP part where it asks for the choice to be made, also, MySQLi is the language used in php to make the connection with the database and all, unless I'm mistaken and I'm sorry if it's the case, also, I get the explanation that Ken Lee gave me here, but how am I supposed to select the room that doesn't get any true answer in this situation ?

Comment: _"that's why I didn't show the PHP part where it asks for the choice to be made"_ - that wasn't the question, the question is why you inserted this into your query _directly_, instead of properly using a placeholder and then binding a parameter to it, same as you did with the two date values.

Comment: _"but how am I supposed to select the room that doesn't get any true answer in this situation ?"_ - if you want the _opposite_ result than what a given condition results in, then you usually _negate_ the condition. (With a condition that is comprised of multiple partial conditions, you need to properly negate the whole thing. If you don't know how, then this would be the time to read up on some basics of Boolean algebra.)

Comment: Oh ! I didn't understand it that way, I didn't use a parameter for '$LeChoix' because it was working without it and I am not really looking for a perfect code here, the project I'm doing in mainly oriented into html, CSS and javascript. The PHP and MySQL part are a complement that I'm trying to learn to make it more complete, so I'm not really into optimizing every variable etc..., but I could do it if it's important ^^

Comment: For the boolean algebra, I understand the concept but I'm really lost when it comes to going through it because I can't visualize the while situation properly, but I'll do some more research for everything, thank you all !